# C - Move array elements up with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I want to perform the following action in C. Is there a way to do this more efficiently with pointers (just out of interest, as I am in the process of learning C). Thanks!

```
int my_array[5];

my_array[0] = my_array[1];
my_array[1] = my_array[2];
my_array[2] = my_array[3];
my_array[3] = my_array[4];
my_array[4] = my_array[5];
my_array[5] = 0;
```

Comment: With modern compilers, array indexing code and pointer code often end up as nearly identical machine code.  Just code it the way that makes most sense.  I vote for `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) my_array[i] = my_array[i+1]; my_array[5] = 0;`.

Comment: you cannot use `my_array[5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `memmove`.

```
memmove(&my_array[0], &my_array[1], 5 * sizeof(my_array[0]));
my_array[5] = 0;
```

Maybe it's the most efficient way, because in most case `memmove` is implemented with special machine code (e.g. `rep movsd` of x86, or SSE..)

(Notice that you **cannot** use `memcpy`, because the source and the destination are overlap. If you use memcpy, *undefined behavior* would come up.)

If you want to copy maually through pointer, you may want this:

```
int *p;
for (p = my_array; p < my_array + 5; p++)
    *p = *(p + 1);
*p = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this...

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
my_array[i]=my_array[i+1];
my_array[i]=0;
```

In array concept the most index is less than 1 of no of elements in that array.Here your array elements 5;But you are trying to access 5th index of array `my_array[5]`. Suppose if you do this operation after initializing array, then you 'll get garbage value in 4th index of array.